# How do I lock down xampp to protect files from been copied

Tags: php, mysql, file, xampp

I want to distribute a webapp using xampp that will be running from the local office machine of my client. I am however very weary that any smart person can simply copy and paste my php files and there goes my business. what are the best ways to prevent both my files and database from been copies when using xampp? The client should not be able to have any direct access to the raw files.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different source file encoding/obfuscation solutions out there, the most famous of which is probably Zend Guard: http://www.zend.com/products/guard

Comment: Wow $600 is not cheap.

Comment: True, but it could be an investment worth making if it protects your business.  It can be used for multiple products and clients.